# Why does this jquery checkbox validation not work?

Tags: jquery

It works in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/A6qhc/) but not in browsers as a stand alone page. I have no idea why, it's dead simple. Please kick me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOME TITLE</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form#my_form').click(function(){ 
    if (! $('input:checkbox')[0].checked){
       alert('Please check the box to agree with the terms and conditions.');
       return false;
    }
}); 

</script>
</head>
<div id="message-trigger" style="display: visible;">
    <p>Now that you completed the required steps you may proceed by agreeing and submitting payment.</p>
    <form id="my_form" method="post" action="">
        <input name="confirmtandc" type="checkbox" value="agree">&nbsp;&nbsp;Please check to verify that you've read and agree with <a href="portal/24/content/tandc.pdf" target="_blank">CMCI terms and conditions</a>.
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to Payment" />

</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `$('form#my_form')` won't target any elements at the time the script instantiates. The DOM is not ready...

Comment: Document ready, duh. Thanks @War10ck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script need to be in a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('form#my_form').click(function () {
        if (!$('input[name="confirmtandc"]').is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please check the box to agree with the terms and conditions.');
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8kVn6/)

Note: in fiddle it works because by default jsfiddle adds the script in a `window.onload` handler - the second dropdown in the left panel